# Can OLAP CUBE be done in HBase?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, ssas, hive, olap-cube

Is there any way to create CUBE DIMENSIONS in HBase or OLAP with it?
I want to create CUBE DIMENSIONS kind of application with my HBASE or HIVE and connect that with SSAS for reporting purpose, is that possible? If soo please guide me with some links and codes.

I have tried to create cube views in hive and i want to know whether that is possible with HBase.

Thanks...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can OLAP be done in BigTable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424132/can-olap-be-done-in-bigtable)

Comment: I want to know how sas could be connected with hive and what would be the performance for reports an visualisation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is quite possible. In fact several attempts have been made in recent past towards the same. See [HBase-Lattice](https://github.com/dlyubimov/HBase-Lattice) and [urbanairship datacube](https://github.com/urbanairship/datacube), for example.

You might also find this [presentation](http://hstack.org/hbasecon-low-latency-olap-with-hbase/) helpful, which talks about **Low Latency “OLAP” with HBase**.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the information. 
I also want to know whether i can go with sas for reporting if i use hive cube dimensions.
I can see that there is sas connectivity with hive.
My doubt is, whether sas imports hive cubes into sas environment and queries there?
or,
It again hits hive for the purpose of reporting so that it runs MR which degrades my reporting performance to more than 2-4 secs.

Comment: I am totally new to sas i want my reports generated with in 2-4 secs where my aggregated data is in Hive tables and then I have created cube dimensions over that.
whether this can be achieved with sas/acess 9.3M2 interface?

Comment: I don't think so(but get it confirmed to be 100% sure). It will just provide you an interface to your Hive data vis SAS. Importing all of your data from there to SAS doesn't make much sense. Have a look at SAS LASR, in case you haven't.

Comment: Thanks
I guess SAS Visual Analytics could do my job
SAS LASR daemons run on each node of your Hadoop cluster.
Based on administrative policies, data is loaded into LASR daemons from the HDFS filesystem.
Soo I guess for reporting can be done over this..
Is there any gap in my understanding?

Answer (score 3):

You can look at [Kylin](http://kylin.incubator.apache.org/) from eBay. It enables you to build cubes from hive and saves the resulting data to hbase